# svn2git kde rules errors - converting tags

Tags: linux, git, svn, git-svn, svn2git

I am using svn2git all fast export and I am getting the following error:

[image: Error 1]
- I had my rules for tags along these lines:

```
match /(<folder>/Source/<folder>/[^/]+/)tags/
  repository repo
  prefix \1
  branch refs/tags/\2
end match
```

How can I correct these rules?

Answer (score 0):

As already told in the comments of your other question, it is probably the invalid backreference you use.
Your rule doesn't make sense.
You have one match group in your regex (thing in parentheses), but you use two back references (backslash + number).
I guess it's erroring out because of that.
Compare your tag rule to my example and you should see the difference.
You miss the `([^/]+)/` in the end of the rule